# ¿Como programo un método Transaccional?

Tags: c#, mysql, método, transacciones

Les comento, necesito realizar varias transacciones en mi desarrollo y me gustara poder realizar un método que me simplifique el trabajo. Tengo un código que encontré en internet pero no se si sea del todo confiable y me gustaría que me dieran una mano con esto. Yo ahora estoy usando MySql como motor de BDD y ha presentado algunas fallas, tal vez tenga algo que ver con el método que estoy usando por eso preferí consultarlo. Si existe algo mejor o alguna optimizacion de esto que ya tengo lo agradecería.

Acá les dejo el código:

```
    public bool ComandosTransaccion(List<String> ListaComandos)
    {
        // VARIABLES PARA HACER LA TRANSACCION
        MySqlTransaction varTransaccion = null;

        try
        {
            Conexion = new MySqlConnection(StringConexion.ToString());
            // ABRIMOS LA CONEXION
            Conexion.Open();

            // Inicializas la transaccion
            varTransaccion = Conexion.BeginTransaction();
            MySqlCommand ComandoSQL = new MySqlCommand();


            //  RECORRO LOS ELEMENTOS DE LA LISTA<STRING> QUE PASE POR PARAMETRO
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaComandos.Count; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ListaComandos[i]);

                // EJECUTO LOS COMANDOS QUE RECIBI POR PARAMETRO COMO PARTE DE LA TRANSACCION
                ComandoSQL = new MySqlCommand(ListaComandos[i], Conexion, varTransaccion);
                ComandoSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // RECIEN DESPUES DE TODO ESTO TERMINA EL PROCESO
            varTransaccion.Commit();
            ComandoSQL.Dispose();

            return true;// RETORNO OK
        }
        catch (Exception evt)
        {
            //SI LA VARIABLE NO ES NULA RELIZAMOS EL ROLLBACK CORRESPONDIENTE 
            if (varTransaccion != null)
            {
                varTransaccion.Rollback();
            }//LANZO MENSAJE DE ERROR DESDE EL METODO EN RUTINAS BDD Y RETORNO FALSO
            MessageBox.Show("Error en la Transaccion - Detalles: "+evt.Message,"Atencion",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return false;//  RETORNO ERROR
        }
```

Comment: Que fallos da ese código? A primera vista, parece correcto

Comment: Aveces cuando realizo una transacción con muchas inserciones y/o actualizaciones se me congela.

Comment: Ojo, no se ve que cierres la conexion nunca. Podra ser por eso?

Comment: Tienes toda razón, ahora lo corrijo y veo como se comporta